# Singlestepping this program is wierd - Compiler error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

If you single-step through this tiny console program in VS2017, you end up executing *both* the **WriteLine(...)** statement *and* the **throw(...)** statement.

This should be *absolutely impossible*, so how can it be???

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Task.Run(() => ProcAsync()).Wait();
        }


        private static async Task ProcAsync()
        {
            int aNumber = 7;

            switch (aNumber)
            {
                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine("The value is 7");  //You first arrive here...
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Oups..?!"); //but then also here!!!??
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I' don't see the expected behavior. Check this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/UEvnKD which Print the `The value is 7` and don't throw any exception after that.

Comment: While it appears to hit the `throw` while debugging, it doesn't actually throw an exception, which would stop debugging and cause the program to fail.

Comment: can confirm debugger visualization bug for VS 2015 as well. the instruction pointer is on a `nop` in the disassembly at that time.

Comment: You don't actually execute both, the debugger is just showing you lies. This issue crops up fairly often, though I can't immediately link us to the various duplicate questions.

Comment: Thank you all for pointing me to the right  explanation. I also found out by myself that the throw statement didn't actually execute, but it felt real scary until I realized that the fault was just a visualization error in the debugger. Have a nice weekend everyone :-)